# How can I have JsonFormat accept more than one pattern?

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I have a variable `effectiveDate` that is an API parameter:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_OR_DATE_AND_TIME_FORMAT)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "effectiveDate")
private Date effectiveDate = null;
```

The current value of `DATE_OR_DATE_AND_TIME_FORMAT` is `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. But I need to be able to accept `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` OR `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. I was doing this with a Regex pattern before, because this was a String, not a Date, but it can no longer be a string and must be a Date. Is there a way to make `pattern` have several values, or something like an `or` statement in a pattern?